# Trying to extract the bytes from a PNG image

Tags: java, image, png, arrays, bufferedimage

I'm trying to extract the bytes from a PNG and am getting some weird looking results.

Here is my extract byte method:

```
public static byte[] extractBytes (String ImageName) throws IOException {
     // open image
     File imgPath = new File(ImageName);
     BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);

     // get DataBufferBytes from Raster
     WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
     DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

     return ( data.getData() );
}
```

And here is where I call the function and loop through the resulting byte[]:

```
byte[] bytes = extractBytes("colorstrip.png");

for (int x : bytes) {
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

I've been testing this code on a 4x1 image simply containing a red pixel, a blue pixel, a green pixel, and a purple pixel in that order. Here is the output:

```
-1
0
0
-1
-1
0
-1
0
-1
-1
0
0
-1
-1
0
-1
```

This output does not look correct to me. I believe the output should look something like this (I've left the alpha channels blank):

```
255
0
0

0
255
0

0
0
255

255
0
255
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java bytes are signed, so when you'd expect 255 in a 0-255 range, java is using a -128 to 127 range and so prints unsigned 255 as signed -1.

Answer (score 2):

What is the type of the BufferedImage? I suspect it's TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR.
Since a byte with value 255 would become -1 in Java, the output seems correct.
-1, 0, 0, -1 = alpha: 255, blue: 0, green: 0, red 255.

Comment: +1 for remembering (apart from the signed Java bytes thing) that a BufferedImage supports severeal internal representations, one should not assume that.